# MYSQL SHELL - SQL MODE from SHELL SCRIPT

Tags: database, bash, shell, mysql

I am writing a shell script to run a sql select query using mysqlsh.

So I had some issues and I found that I need to use "\sql" to change it from

mysql-js> to mysql-sql>

I need to run /sql before I run the query from a file.

```
"C:\mysql-shell-1.0.11-windows-x86-64bit\bin\mysqlsh.exe" echo \sql | mysql://user@IP:PORT?schema=SCHEMANAME&password=PASSWORD
```

and then execute this to run the select query and save it to a tmpfile.txt

```
"C:\mysql-shell-1.0.11-windows-x86-64bit\bin\mysqlsh.exe" --file "$EDIR"/data/tmp.sql > "$EDIR"/data/tmpfile.txt 2>&1
```

I am not sure what am missing. I tried different alternatives,

I am getting the below error on the first line
**"data_extractss.sh: line 53: mysql://user@IP:PORT?schema=SCHEMANAME&password=PASSWORD: No such file or directory"**

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: your command line consider your string like a path file. Try to write it like : `"C:\mysql-shell-1.0.11-windows-x86-64bit\bin\mysqlsh.exe" echo \sql | "mysql://user@IP:PORT?schema=SCHEMANAME&password=PASSWORD"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, please upgrade to the latest version of the shell 8.0.12

Second, start the shell like 'mysqlsh --sql' or 'mysqlsh --sqlc' to have it start in SQL mode

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks I have updated it, the documentation says that if the file is a ".sql" file, mysql shell automatically takes care of it irrespective of the default mode.

My problem now is I have removed the "echo \sql". that line goes through, the second commands throws me an error saying its not connected. I think the session is not held back after the line is executed.